# Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have multiple projects in a Visual Studio 2019 C# MVC solution.
I have upgraded all the projects to use Framework 4.5 from 4.0
From this got a few errors and advice via SO was to upgrade my EntityFramework.
So using NuGet, upgraded from EF 5.0.0 to EF 6.0.0

And I get this error.
I've been through many SO posts to no avail.

I have no EntityFramework reference in my GAC
All my project references show EntityFramwork at 6.0.0

I took a backup of my solution prior to starting this and have tried multiple suggestions according to SO posts.

I've removed EF 5 via NuGet. Then installed EF 6 using the same.
I've removed references and re-added them.
I've closed down VS.
Updated EF via Package Manager.

All to no effect.

What am I missing please?
Do you need any other code snippets?

All my project references for EntityFramework.dll show the correct path to ...\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll. They have runtime version of v4.0.30319, Specific Version set to True and Version set to 6.0.0.0

Some code snippets:
All my configs have this in it

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

My csproj files all have this in it

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: Your project(s) need to use same version of Net.  So first you have to make sure all the project do a clean build.  Second, Net does not do a good job of updating project when Net is updated.  The compiler dependencies do not recognize when a version of Net is changed.  Often the version number in the .proj is wrong and causes errors like yours.  Building a project from scratch will solve this issue but is a lot of work.

Comment: I often create a new project with just the library (don't need code just using statement at top of module) that is giving an issue.  Then compile new project and compare the version of library in .proj file of new and old project.  Then edit the version number in old code to look like new code.  This works most of the time.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the feedback. Checked all the projects and they're all on Framework 4.5. I will try your other suggestion too. But if that doesn't work, I guess it's rebuild time. I really do hate Microsoft sometimes...................

Comment: If you get one project working then compare old and new .proj files.  You may just need a simple edit to the .proj file.

Comment: @jdweng just one further question as I don't think I made this clear in my OP. My projects do in fact build cleanly.The issue and error don't happen within VS. I only get the error when I start to debug the application on localhost. Technically I guess that is still within VS but does this distinction give any further clues as to where it might be wrong?

Comment: You are getting a run-time error because an issue inside the library dll.  there is an incompatibility between the Net Library installed and other libraries used by the dll.  Many of the Net dlls call windows dll.  So you are going from Net 4.0 (had two versions both 32 bit and 64 bit) to Net 4.5 (64 bit).  What options are you using for project : x86, x64, Any CPU?  What is your target Net Version (Net 4.5 you can still target Net 4.0)?  The windows dll version are different for Net 4.0 and Net 4.5.  So issue could be Net dlls, Windows dlls, or both.

Comment: v4.0.30319 is Net 4.0 and you shouldn't be using Net 4.0 if you upgraded to Net 4.5.  You can target Net 4.0 with Net 4.5 but the library will not be 30319.

Comment: @jdweng There are 9 projects. All are using Any CPU. All have their target version set to 4.5. I've looked on regedit at the framework setup. I have 4.7.03062 as the version. But production environment is only 4.5, hence I'm restricted. But in regedit, it also says the path is Framework64\v4.0.30319 and TargetVersion is 4.0.0
I've not had to delve this deeply before into the nuts and bolts of frameworks so this is a little beyond me.

Comment: If it still says 30319 then it doesn't look like those object were recompiled with Net 4.7.  You can check the the dates of the dlls to see the last time of being compiled.To force a project to get recompiled I sometimes backup the bin folder and then delete.  When working with multiple projects you should never copy the dlls into a project bin folder.Instead all project should be added using Add Existing object and then browse to the source bin folder and select the executable. Your csproj would look like this : <Reference Include="ABC">
      <HintPath>.\ABC.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>